# How to import XML data into postgres database table?

Tags: plpgsql

I have XML format file for account table created using query as:
SELECT table_to_xml('account', true, FALSE, '');

-----The table structure is as:
CREATE TABLE public.account (
  account_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  type VARCHAR(20),
  group_name VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT account_pkey PRIMARY KEY(account_id));

---

Question: How can I directly load data into account table using XML file in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use varchar(2) due to the conversion from xml.

I've used a select into (creates public.account)

```
select account_id::text::int, account_name::varchar(2),
account_type::varchar(20) , account_group::varchar(50) INTO
public.account from(
WITH x AS ( SELECT
'<accounts>
<account>
<account_id>1</account_id>
<account_name> A </account_name>
<account_type> off shore</account_type>
<account_group> slush fund </account_group>
</account>
<account>
<account_id>3</account_id>
<account_name> C </account_name>
<account_type> off shore</account_type>
<account_group> slush fund </account_group>
</account>
</accounts> '::xml AS t)

SELECT unnest(xpath('/accounts/account/account_id/text()', t)) 
AS account_id,
   unnest(xpath('/accounts/account/account_name/text()', t)) 
AS account_name,
   unnest(xpath('/accounts/account/account_type/text()', t)) 
AS account_type,
   unnest(xpath('/accounts/account/account_group/text()', t)) 
AS account_group

FROM   x) as accounts
```

If you're interested in reading the xml file in then this may be useful.

Ref [stackexchange sql to read xml from file into postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8172/sql-to-read-xml-from-file-into-postgresql-database)

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes...I will try...Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hi MOnalee Bhandge can you help other find the solution? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235